# Is there a better way to wash home-made butter?

Tags: butter

Freshly-churned butter has to be washed clean of residual buttermilk to keep well.
The only method I've seen recommended is to massage the butter by hand in changes of iced water.

This can be quite uncomfortable and a little cumbersome.. I wondered whether anyone had come up with a neater procedure they use regularly. ( I imagine, perhaps, pushing the butter through a potato ricer, rolling it out, food-processing with very cold water.. other speculations.. ).

Is there any experience out there?

Answer (score 3):

I use a stand mixer with a dough hook attachment, and ice water. It usually takes 3 changes of ice water.

Answer (score 0):

Just from my experience making it at home and at work, once you’ve separated it from the solids, grab the smallest stainless steel bowl that can fit the butter and keep on flipping it and draining the bowl. It sounds a little stupid but it lets you clean up and do other stuff while you flip.

Comment: What do you mean by “keep on flipping it”? Just keep turning the mass of butter over, rather than kneading it in the water?